# Horizontal tangents of $xe^{-x^2-x^{-2}}$

Tags: calculus

I'm following Christian Parkinson GRE prep course. In example 14 of the week 1 prep course notes, we need to find the number of horizontal tangents to the function

$f(0) = 0$, and $f(x)=xe^{-x^2-x^{-2}}$ for $x\neq 0$.

I ran through the differentiation to get two values of $x$ where $x^2 = \frac{1+\sqrt{17}}{4}$. However, Christian's notes state the following which I don't quite understand:

> We also note that as $x\rightarrow 0$,
>   $\frac{f(x)}{x}\rightarrow 0$, so indeed, f is differentiable at $x = 0$ with $f'(0) = 0$. Thus the answer is 3.

Question: Why are we considering $\frac{f(x)}{x}\rightarrow 0$, and in what cases do we need to start thinking about other "solutions" after solving $f'(x)=0$?

Thanks!

[Link](https://www.math.ucla.edu/~chparkin/gre.html) for reference.

Comment: Thanks Eric - I've updated the question with how $f(x)$ is actually defined in his notes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since $f$ is defined piecewise, we must be careful at the edges of the pieces.  There is only one such edge, at $x = 0$.  We look at the difference quotient
$$  \frac{f(x) - f(0)}{x - 0} = \frac{f(x)}{x} $$
and take the limit as $x \rightarrow 0$ to determine if the function is differentiable (the limit exists) and has derivative zero (the value of the limit is zero).